# What is WGM22:0 and WGM2:0 for ATmega328?

Tags: atmega

I have question what is the difference between (WGM22:0 = 1 or 5)  and  WGM2:0 = 3  as shown in image with red lined?

My understanding is WGM22:0 is really WGM2(2..0) which is 3 bits.  What is WGM2:0?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The register is `WGM2` and has three bits, so is properly `WGM2[2:0]`, which are in registers: it's the **w**aveform **g**eneration **m**ode for timer 2.  There are also the same controls for other timers.

Sometimes they somewhat sloppily write `WGM22` for `WGM2[2]`.  `WGM20 = 3` in your example only makes sense as `WGM2[2:0] = 3`.  `MGM` appears to be a typo for `WGM`.

**HOWEVER** Those numbers appear wrong, and are apparently cut-and-paste from "Fast PWM".  In the current version of the datasheet ([link](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061B.pdf), "Rev. 8271A – 12/09"), has some of the same mistakes, but I believe the table 18-8 is correct.

In general it seems that tables are checked much more carefully in datasheets than running text. In a long datasheet such as for a CPU with a lot of repetition there is always the risk of copy-paste errors.

[image]

The following is for a **DIFFERENT REGISTER** but is what I think it should be for `WGM2[2:0]`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks HOWEVER, that's what I thought they both meant WGM2(2..0). Yes, I do think it should be WGM2(2..0) = 1 or 5. 3 and 7 is for FAST PWM. Thanks

Comment: Funny I click your link and downloaded the datasheet, it's EXACTLY like mine, it's not like you copy of 1 and 5. Thanks

Comment: I think you read mid-edit (apologies).  I believe the WGM bits are the same across all the timers.  In general it appears that datasheet tables are checked much more carefully than running text, and seem more reliable.

Comment: I edited to clarify this is for a different timer.